# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b)

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2015

I am getting error as Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.] System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0 System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37 System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159 System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80 System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22 System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29 System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39 [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.] System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777 System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229 System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +99 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +310 System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165 System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590 [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.] System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10087352 System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

Could you please help me on this.
Did I missed something?

Comment: That type of exception is usually (if not always) raised when trying to run 64 bit libraries in 32 bit systems or viceversa. Have you tried this search? [stackoverflow - BadImageFormatException + Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+BadImageFormatException+Oracle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)